# Find the distance from any node in tree

Tags: python-2.7, recursion, tree

I am trying to get the depth of the node from other nodes in the following tree. I have a list with the parent-child relationship:

```
Parent -> Children

[2] -> [0]

[1] -> [2,5]

[5] -> [3,4,6]
```

I want to find the depth/distance of one node from other nodes.
So, from node `[5]`, the `depth[]={3,1,2,1,1,0,1}`

I currently have:

```
def get_depth(self,idx,depth):

        self.depth[idx]=depth
        for child in self.sentence_prop.words[idx].children:
            get_depth(child[0],depth+1)
        return
```

where idx=`[5]` and initial `depth=0`. I did this only for the child but I am not sure how to do it for parent.

Comment: This seems unclear to me. Can you illustrate more input and output examples? What is the output for `0`? Are the numbers always sequential `1` to `n`?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this solves your problem.

1) The distance between 2 nodes is given by this formulae:

> **Dist(n1, n2) = Dist(root, n1) + Dist(root, n2) - 2*Dist(root,
>   lca)**

Here lca : Lowest common ancestor of n1 and n2. This works in any general tree.

2) What you need to do:

1. Store paths corresponding to each node you want to find distance
   of
2. Iterate through the paths to find the common path length.
3. `return (len(path1)+len(path2)-2*(common_path_length))`

The implementation of this concept for a binary tree is [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-distance-between-two-nodes-of-a-binary-tree/)